# Twitter PHP - URL not encoded in tweet

Tags: php, url, twitter

I'm trying to post to Twitter using the Twitter PHP SDK [twitter-async](https://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async) my tweets include a URL in them that doesn't seem to be getting encoded. How can I make the URLs show properly when tweeted?

I call this function in the SDK

```
function postTweet($tweet) {
  $this->twitterObj->post('/statuses/update.json', array('status' => $tweet));            
}
```

There's not much to it really.

Comment: please post some code and output

Comment: Added the function that I call in the Twitter lib

Comment: It just posts the $tweet passed it to Twitter, as plain text, the URL doesn't show as a link you can click in the stream

Comment: I mean, what is the value of $tweet, and what shows up on Twitter?

Comment: It's just a text the user wishes and a URL, it all shows up on twitter properly, except that the URL doesn't show up as a link but as plain text, so people can't click on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was simply an issue with Twitter not recognizing my local URL as an url, when I tested changing to my production site it worked fine.